# Math PHD program with no GRE scores

Tags: graduate-admissions

I'm a fresh graduate from a B.S. in mathematics program and am looking to go to graduate school. I have a strong cumulative GPA of 3.7 and have secured 3 letters of recommendation for the future.  Despite this however, a mandatory 1 year military service program prevents me taking any GRE exams before most application deadlines. I was planning to apply during my service and start the following fall (2019). But I'm afraid that not having GRE scores will significantly hurt my chances. Should I just take all my GRE exams during my service and apply for the fall 2020 term?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Many schools require the GRE and will not waive it.

Comment: Why does military service prevent you from taking the GRE?

Comment: This depends what country (and sometimes even the subject area and institute) you plan on applying in. For instance, for mathematics in Canada the GRE is not usually required and most students don't write it.  Which country are you planning on applying to graduate school in?

Comment: I'm thinking US, Canada, UK, and maybe France or Germany. Outside the US though, I'll need a masters degree to apply for a PHD. That's what I've heard.

Comment: As for Glen' s question, during this mandatory service, you pretty much have no freedom. So I'd be forced to wait.

Answer (score 2):

GRE is more or less compulsory for graduate admission in the US. You will need better reason than 1-year military service for not taking it in your application.

Please take the exams and apply for the fall 2020 term.

Answer (score 0):

Take the GRE now. Scores are valid for 3-5 years after taking it.